# Pegando valores de variáveis iguais pela URL

Tags: php

Me compliquei um pouco no titulo para explicar a minha duvida, porém tentarei ser o mais claro possível.

Tenho esse campo:

[image: Meu campo]

Preciso pegar os valores que foram selecionados no campo ramais, porem quando pego o resultado dele via POST ele só trás um valor e via GET também, porém ele trás isso na URL:

```
https://192.168.0.27/projetos/bdm/grupo_de_permicao.php?formfield1=teste&my_multi_select1=200&my_multi_select1=4864&my_multi_select1=2000
```

Queria saber se tem como pegar todos esses valores com a mesma variável `my_multi_select1` e jogar dentro de um array ou alguma outra maneira.

Acredito que não seja de muita serventia mas, segue abaixo o meu código:

```
<div class="form-group">
                               <label class="form-label" for="formfield1">Ramais</label>
                                    <span class="desc">Adicione ou remova os ramais utilizando a caixa abaixo</span>
                                    <select name="my_multi_select1" class="multi-select form-control" multiple="" id="my_multi_select1" name="formfield2">

                                        <?php
                                $allramal = "";
                                $tst2 = selectRamals();
                                while ($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($tst2)) {
                                  ?>
                                    <option value="<?=$linha['extension']?>"><?=$linha['name']?>   (<?=$linha['extension']?>)</option>
                                <?php } ?>
                                    </select>      
                                </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recomendo via POST, porque como todos sabemos, o GET tem limite de caracteres que depende do navegador, e se tratando de algo que o cliente pode fazer muitas seleções, talvez dê problema via GET.

Faça assim (fiz um exemplo voltado ao seu negócio, mas sem usar o Bootstrap, pra servir de modelo para outras pessoas e tornar o código mais simples, basta re-adaptar).

```
<form action="" method="post">
<select name="my_multi_select1[]" multiple="multiple">
    <?php
        $allramal = "";
        $tst2 = selectRamals();
        while ($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($tst2)) {
            echo "<option value='{$linha['extension']}'>{$linha['name']} ({$linha['extension']})</option>";
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

Perceba que no nome do input, nós colocamos um `[]` pra indicar pro PHP que a variável que irá receber os valores desse campo, deve ser um array.

Pra imprimir na tela, faça:

```
print_r($_POST['my_multi_select1']);
```

**Obs.:** quando estiver re-escrevendo o código, arrume o nome do input onde tem as options, você definiu a propriedade name duas vezes no mesmo campo.

Comment: Valeu!! Não vou conseguir te responder agora mas amanhã eu vou testar e comentar aqui!! Valeuzao

Comment: Está certo. O `[]` irá criar uma `array` do `my_multi_select1`. Para acessar cada  um pode usar o `foreach($_POST['my_multi_select1'] as $multi){ echo $multi; }`

Comment: Valeu!! Certíssimo

Answer (score 0):

Recomendo que use $_POST pois é mais seguro e não há limitações como $_GET

E você pode manipular esses resultados com Foreach
**[Foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.foreach.php)**

```
foreach($_POST['my_multi_select1'] as $value)
{ 

   echo $value; 


}
```